# Labels of the variables on the histogram

Tags: python, pandas, histogram, axis-labels

so I have a data frame in which the column 'Art_Label' has a Label with a classification of the article, possible values are: 'politica', 'deportes', 'elmundo', 'otros', 'policiales', 'economia', 'editorial'

Here is the code from the top

```
data = pd.read_csv('/filename.csv', sep=',')
    data = data.drop('Unnamed: 0', axis=1)
    data.columns
```

> > > Index([u'Date', u'Title', u'Encabezado', u'Art_Label', u'Media'], dtype='object')

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

df =  data['Art_Label']
df2 = df.value_counts()
df2.plot(kind = 'hist', xlim = (0,400))
print df2
```

I want to create a histogram with each Label and its frequency, I managed to get the frequency using ´df2 = df.value_counts()´, I would like to be able to get the Label of each value on the histogram:

These are the results that I get from ´df2 = df.value_counts()´

```
politica      332
deportes      323
elmundo       192
otros         191
policiales    137
economia      132
editorial      96
Name: Art_Label, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

A little confused about your questions. Do you want the figure? If so, I think 'bar' is what u want...

```
MM = pd.Series([332, 323, 192, 191, 137, 132, 96], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'])

MM.plot(kind = 'bar', xlim = (0,400))
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGIET.png)